# interval() with delay based on value

Tags: rxjs

What is the best way to make observable interval that will emit Integers and each new value with a delay of this value (in seconds)?

```js
interval().subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

expected:

```
1  --- after 1 second
2  --- 2 seconds after 1 was emitted
...
37 --- 37 seconds after 36 was emitted
...
```

I've created sandbox for you - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-task-delay?file=index.ts

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are looking for, is it that you want the delay to be 1s, then 2s, then 3s, ... iterating with each trigger?

Comment: yes, exactly. we output integers with delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use mergeMap, all inner Observables are subscribed right after they are created, so we don't get increasing time gaps, because `interval` emits **every second**, so all inner observables are subscribe right after source emits:

```
source.pipe(
  mergeMap(num => of(num).pipe(
    delay(num * 1000)
  )
)

emits 1 after 1 sec., inner waits 1 sec 
emits 2 after 1 sec., inner waits 2 sec (1 sec already passed)
emits 3 after 1 sec., inner waits 3 sec (2 secs already passed)
```

But with `concatMap` inner are not subscribed until previous completed:

```
source.pipe(
  concatMap(num => of(num).pipe(
    delay(num * 1000)
  )
)
```

[Sandbox example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-task-delay-vmvvn4?file=index.ts)

Comment: could you please update sandbox (link provided above)? you will see that it does not work

Comment: Sure, edited my answer (I didnt checked your snippet. Next time, better add code to the question, so its easier for everyone )

Comment: maybe I describe it not so clear, let me adjust the description. I should be different delete between them (not 1s for all)

Comment: Oh, ok I think I got your point. Replace `mergeMap` with `concatMap`, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
import {  BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'; 


const sub = new BehaviorSubject(1);

sub.subscribe( val => {
  console.log( val);
  setTimeout( () => {sub.next(val+1);}, val*1000);
  });
```

Play with it at https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-task-delay-41r4b1

Comment: I give you +1 for alternative solution, but in this case (if you are using setTimeout) I think you don't need rxjs at all :)

Comment: I am using `rxjs` so you can have an observable there, you could also have a regular variable and rely on change detection everywhere (at least in my Angular language).